# I am trying to add the sum of three numbers in JavaScript but it's giving me NaN. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function, arguments

I am wanting to collect three numbers from the user and add them using a function and loop. I keep coming up with NaN. Why is this? I've tried converting the string prompt to a Number object to resolve this.

```js
var userEntry1 = Number(window.prompt("Enter in a number of your choice"));
var userEntry2 = Number(window.prompt("Enter in a number of your choice"));
var userEntry3 = Number(window.prompt("Enter in a number of your choice"));
var sum;
var i;
function addNumb(userEntry1, userEntry2, userEntry3) {
    "use strict";
    sum = userEntry1 + userEntry2 + userEntry3;
    for (i = 1; i <= arguments.length; i += 1) {
        sum += Number(arguments[i]);

    }
    return sum;
    
}

addNumb(userEntry1, userEntry2, userEntry3);
window.console.log(sum);
```

Comment: The `arguments` object has indexes that run from 0 to `arguments.length - 1`. It's not clear why you even *need* it, because your function takes three named arguments as it is and adds them together. What are you trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: You're adding `arguments[3]` which is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already summing the three entered numbers (`sum = userEntry1 + userEntry2 + userEntry3;`) and don't need the for loop at all. If you have to use a `for` loop, then you should delete the `sum = userEntry1 + userEntry2 + userEntry3;` line. With `"use strict"` you will then have to remove the function argument declarations to avoid "variable is declared but not used" errors.

```js
var userEntry1 = Number(window.prompt("Enter in a number of your choice"));
var userEntry2 = Number(window.prompt("Enter in a number of your choice"));
var userEntry3 = Number(window.prompt("Enter in a number of your choice"));

function addNumb(userEntry1, userEntry2, userEntry3) {
    "use strict";
    var sum = userEntry1 + userEntry2 + userEntry3;
    return sum;       
}

function addNumb2() {
    "use strict";
    for (var i = 0, sum = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        sum += Number(arguments[i]);
    }
    return sum;
}

console.log(addNumb(userEntry1, userEntry2, userEntry3));
console.log(addNumb2(userEntry1, userEntry2, userEntry3));
```

Comment: I'm required to use the loop.

Comment: Then you should delete the `sum = userEntry1 + userEntry2 + userEntry3;` line. See my edit which has a version which only uses the `for` loop

Comment: It works fine on this site, but in Brackets it gives me a parsing error.

Comment: Parsing error: Unexpected token i    for (let i = 0, sum = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {

Comment: @jp96 ah your JS doesn't support `let`, try changing it to `var`

Comment: seemed like that worked, however, now userEntry3 is saying that it's defined but never used.

Comment: @jp96 Brackets is fussy! You need to remove the argument definitions then, so change it to `function addNumb2() {` (see my edit)

Comment: Why did you add sum = 0 into the loop?

Comment: @jp96 that `sum = 0` only gets executed at the beginning of the loop (at the same time as `i` gets set to 0). It's the same as writing `var sum = 0; for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {`

Answer (score 2):

In your loop, you're looping equal to the length of `arguments`, but since it's a 0-based array, you're going one iteration too far. Change the `<=` to `<`:

```js
var userEntry1 = Number(window.prompt("Enter in a number of your choice"));
var userEntry2 = Number(window.prompt("Enter in a number of your choice"));
var userEntry3 = Number(window.prompt("Enter in a number of your choice"));
var sum;
var i;

function addNumb(userEntry1, userEntry2, userEntry3) {
  "use strict";
  sum = userEntry1 + userEntry2 + userEntry3;
  for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i += 1) {
    sum += Number(arguments[i]);

  }
  return sum;

}

addNumb(userEntry1, userEntry2, userEntry3);
window.console.log(sum);
```

Comment: I'm sorry @Ele, I can't see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `arguments` object has keys from `0`, so you should loop thru that object from `0` to the `keys.length - 1`.

The object `arguments` is actually a `key-value` object, so you can use the operator `in`.

```js
var userEntry1 = Number(window.prompt("Enter in a number of your choice")),
    userEntry2 = Number(window.prompt("Enter in a number of your choice")),
    userEntry3 = Number(window.prompt("Enter in a number of your choice")),
    sum,
    i;

function addNumb(userEntry1, userEntry2, userEntry3) {
  console.log(arguments)// keys from zero to keys.length - 1
  "use strict";
  sum = userEntry1 + userEntry2 + userEntry3;
  for (var arg in arguments) sum += Number(arguments[arg]);
  return sum;
}

addNumb(userEntry1, userEntry2, userEntry3);
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer. I'm really new to JS. When I tried your code in the text editor, it gave me a bunch of errors.